# How to use hatch pattern in baposter header box?

Tags: baposter, pattern

I'd like to try using hatch in my header box or box background within baposter. With the template I'm using, you can only input headerColorOne, and can't dictate pattern or fill. How would I go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer sets up the header as a `node`, fills the header with a single color and overlays a pattern.

The same approach can be used in text box section of the `\posterbox`.

This is the output.

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{baposter}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
        grid=false,
        columns=6, % how many columns 1-6
        colspacing=5.0mm, % spacing between the columns
        headerheight=0cm, % the height of the header for the title
        background=none, %user or none or plain
        eyecatcher=false, %turn left logo on/off
        %posterbox options
        headerborder=closed, % see the baposter manual for the rest
        borderColor=darkgray,
        headershape=rectangle,
        headershade=plain,
        headerColorOne=white,
        textborder=rectangle,
        boxshade=plain,
        boxColorOne=white,
        headerFontColor=black,
        textfont=\tiny,
        headerfont=\normalsize\bfseries,
        linewidth=1pt,
    }
    {}{\textcolor{white}{dummy}}{}{} % Eyecatcher, title, author, right logo. There must be at least one entry.

\begin{posterbox}[name=box1, column=0, span=1]{%
        \tikz{\node[
                preaction={%
                fill,                     % fill the header with red!50!white
                red!50!white
                },
                text width=\boxwidth-4ex, % specify the text width to set the width of the fill
                pattern=north east lines, % overlay a pattern of north east lines
                pattern color=white      
            ] 
            {Header};
        }
}
Some text
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, which is a wonderful resource for learning LaTeX and finding solutions to problems. It relies on questions being supported by the OP uploading a minimum working example. The TeX.SE starter guide is here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx